# Docker build error - cannot find the file when executed from windows

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, dockerfile, visual-studio-2022

The docker file that was initially added from the visual studio was successfully built while executing it from the visual studio and created mydevdockerimage image. Here is my Dockerfile execution code:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyDevApp/MyDevApp.csproj", "MyDevApp/"]
COPY ["Application.Models/Application.Models.csproj", "Application.Models/"]
COPY ["ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj", "ApplicationCore/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyDevApp/MyDevApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyDevApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyDevApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyDevApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyDevApp.dll"]
```

But when the `docker build -t mydevdockerimage .` is executed from Windows to update the image it throws an error, did not find the file to copy.

```
 => ERROR [build  3/10] COPY [MyDevApp/MyDevApp.csproj, MyDevApp/]                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [build  4/10] COPY [Application.Models/Application.Models.csproj, Application.Models/]                   0.0s
 => ERROR [build  5/10] COPY [ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj, ApplicationCore/]                            0.0s
 => ERROR [build  6/10] COPY [Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj, Infrastructure/]                               0.0s
------
 > [build  3/10] COPY [MyDevApp/MyDevApp.csproj, MyDevApp/]:
------
------
 > [build  4/10] COPY [Application.Models/Application.Models.csproj, Application.Models/]:
------
------
 > [build  5/10] COPY [ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj, ApplicationCore/]:
------
------
 > [build  6/10] COPY [Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj, Infrastructure/]:
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     COPY ["MyDevApp/MyDevApp.csproj", "MyDevApp/"]
  11 |     COPY ["Application.Models/Application.Models.csproj", "Application.Models/"]
  12 | >>> COPY ["ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj", "ApplicationCore/"]
  13 |     COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
  14 |     RUN dotnet restore "MyDevApp/MyDevApp.csproj"
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 2bcf51c1-1b04-4058-8dcc-e84f1c6efad2::zubu32h4st3t4uebsy26mpgti: "/ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj": not found
```

And this is how my folder structure looks like:

```
- MyDevApp-Web
   - Infrastructure
        - Infrastructure.csproj
   - Application.Models
        - Application.Models.csproj
   - ApplicationCore
        - ApplicationCore.csproj
   - MyDevApp
        - MyDevApp.csproj
        - Dockerfile
```

Here MyDevApp has a dependency on the Application.Models, ApplicationCore and Infrastructure. Can you please tell me how to fix this error? For now, I am deleting older images and rebuilding using Visual studio every time I have some changes. But that is not an optimal way and takes so much of my time. Can anyone please help?

Comment: That means the path is wrong. This isn't a Windows issue. You *don't* have to copy the other projects, as long as the root project has a project reference to them. That's why the .NET/Visual Studio project templates add only the root project to the Dockerfile

Comment: Why did you add the extra COPY commands? Did you have a problem building the Dockerfile? That's probably because the *context* (ie root folder) specified when building the Dockerfile is wrong. When you build the Dockerfile in VS, the correct path is used as the context (MyDevApp-Web). When you try to build the Dockerfile from the command line you need to specify it yourself. Eg, go into `MyDevApp-Web` and type `docker build . -f MyDevApp/Dockerfile`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you were right ```docker build . -f MyDevApp/Dockerfile``` did the job. But do we have to mention which image to update because initially it created appdevelopment image.